# Is it possible to make webpack output some text from within a file it's compiling?

Tags: webpack

For example if I'm offering a library and I want to deprecate some features of it, could I possibly get webpack to output a message when it compiles that file? For example:

```js
/* webpack-warning: ourDeprecatedFunction is deprecated. */
const ourDeprecatedFunction = () => {
...
}
```

I see we have other compiler directives such as `/* webpackChunkName: "my-chunk" */` so wondering what else is possible.

I will also be outputting messages in the browser console, but I want to make this message as visible as posisble.